# function with parameters as an array with objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I had a problem where i sa feeding an Function with an array with objects inside.

```
var func = function (){
    var feeded = //here is my problem
    /*some code/*
}

var itemArray = [{"stat":49,"amount":156},{"stat":40,"amount":108},{"stat":5,"amount":207},{"stat":7,"amount":311}] //just an exsample
var answare = func(itemArray)
```

How do i med the variable feeded the same as itemArray, so i can use the methods for arrays on feeded?

I have tried useing:

```
var feeded = [].slice.call(arguments)
```

and

```
var feeded = arguments
```

I could not use a for loop and then get  the stat and amount inside. (i am not needing to close lines as it is not needed in google script

Comment: You are overthinking it. `var func = function(feeded) { ... }` should work for you, given that you are invoking it with `func(itemArray)`. Alternately, `var func = function() { var feeded = arguments[0]; ... }`, if you really, *really* hate that parameter there. It would be a different matter if you invoked `func.apply(this, itemArray)`, but there is no reason to.

Comment: You should read a tutorial about functions, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions or http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: if you say `var func = funtion(feeded), feeded is only the first object, as all that is feeded to the funtion becomes an array, you juts name the first object inside the array

Comment: @MeltinglavaOutland: As I said, as long as you are passing one argument, like `func(itemArray)`, you are only getting a single argument in the function. You don't need to access `arguments` unless you want to handle the syntax `func()`, `func(item)`, `func(item, item)`... and not `func(itemArray)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can iterate those with a for Loop

```
var func = function (){
    var feeded = arguments;
    console.log(arguments);
    for(var i = 0; i < feeded[0].length; i++)
        console.log(feeded[0][i].stat);
}

var itemArray = [{"stat":49,"amount":156},{"stat":40,"amount":108},{"stat":5,"amount":207},{"stat":7,"amount":311}] //just an exsample
var answare = func(itemArray)
```

You might just have forgot to access `arguments[0]` instead of `arguments`

Comment: what is `arguments` ??

Comment: arguments is an array of arguments given, but not defined in parameters of function e.g. `func('a', 'b');` would have `arguments[0] == 'a'` and `arguments[1] == 'b'`

Comment: `arguments` is a key world?/

Comment: `arguments` isn't quite an array, but `[].slice.call(arguments)` will return its contents as an array.

Comment: So it is an array inside an array. That explains why i got `arguments.length` = 1.

Comment: No one said it's an "array inside an array". I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Ah, I get it: You meant that if you make the array the first argument to the function, then the array becomes the first element of `arguments`, which is itself (almost) an array. And `arguments.length` is the number of arguments supplied to the function, not the length of the first argument. (That would be `arguments[0].length`, although it would be more conventional to give the argument a name so it would become `feeded.length` or something.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the function accept a parameter. Simply put a suitable name for the parameter in the parentheses of your the function declaration like this:

```
var func = function(items){
    [...]
}
```

Inside the function, you can access the parameter by simply using it's name. In your case it would be like this:

```
var func = function(items){
    var feeded = items;
}
```

You can read more about functions in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var func = function (){
    var feeded = arguments; //is itemArray Array
    console.log(feeded)
    /*some code*/
}

var itemArray = [{"stat":49,"amount":156},{"stat":40,"amount":108},{"stat":5,"amount":207},{"stat":7,"amount":311}] //just an exsample
var answare = func.apply(null, itemArray)
```

Comment: what is `arguments` ??

Comment: `arguments` = `itemArray[]`